# Show that if $AB=A$ and $B\not=I$ then $A$ has to be singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> $A$ and $B$ are nonzero, square matrices. Show that if $AB=A$ and $B\not=I$ then $A$ has to be singular. That is, if $B$ is not the identity matrix of the same dimensions as $A$.

I understand that if $A$ has one $i$ row entirely of zeroes, then the corresponding entry of $B$ for $i=j$ could have any value different for $1$ and it won't affect the outcome because the zeroes would nullify it in the multiplication process. But how do I write a formal proof?

Comment: What does "B diff from B" mean?

Comment: @Deepak, fixed... thanks.

Comment: The statement is false. Take A as the zero matrix and B as anything but I.

Comment: @DavidCabrera Use latex/mathjax to typeset mathematical formulas on this site. It is not hard to learn and you can find more information [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon the statement is not wrong, my question was wrong then... let me fix it to specify. Sorry, first question on the forum.

Comment: @Winther I'm sorry, first time using the site. I don't get why 4 downvotes, it's evident that this is my first question, why downvote it 4 times instead of just giving advice?

Comment: I agree that the number downvotes is excessive. It's a bad habit people have on this site. Don't worry too much about it. The question is after your edit fine imo and will hopefully be reopened. Just try to make sure in the future that you write clear questions, add context / your own try and typeset it well and you will hopefully get a much better response. Welcome to this site btw!

Comment: If $A$ is nonsingular then it has an inverse which we can apply to get $A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}A \implies B = I$. Thus it cannot be that $A$ is non-singular and $B$ not being the identity. Did you perhaps mean to say "then $A$ is singular" instead?

Comment: @David. Yes. I am certain. This statement is false.

Comment: @Winther, Yes, I'm so sorry. The question on the book is that the matrix has to be singular. I already found a case, but I would like to determine if it is the only possible case of $AB=A$ when $B$ is not the identity matrix. I'll describe the case thoroughly in my question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon, I'm sorry, you are right, I thought that I wrote "singular". Otherwise the whole question would be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $A$ is not singular. Then there exists an inverse $A^{-1}$ of $A$. Multiplication of the equation
$$AB = A$$
from the left by $A^{-1}$ yields
$$A^{-1} A B = A^{-1} A.$$
Hence
$$B = I.$$

Comment: @azimuth I get it now, I was trying to prove it in an affirmative way, and the proof required was by contradiction, thanks :)